# Gradient-jump penalty term in FEM

Tags: finite-element, numerics, discontinuous-galerkin, deal.ii

I am slightly confused regarding the meaning of the **$i-th$** gradient-jump term $[\nabla \phi_i]$ in the context of finite element methods, used in the assembly of the stiffness matrix (an example with [`deal.ii`](https://www.dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/step_12.html)). On face $F$ with unit normal $\nu$, the jump term is defined as
$$
[\nabla \phi ] = \nu \cdot (\nabla\phi^+-\nabla\phi^-)
$$
For example, consider the case of a Lagrangian, bilinear quadrilateral element, where $i \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. We want to compute the gradient-jump penalty term on face $F$
\begin{gather}
\int_F [\nabla u][\nabla \phi] \tag{$\star$}
\end{gather}
But we see that, since $u = \sum_i \phi_i u_i$ and $u_0^+ \equiv u_3^-$, $u_1^+ \equiv u_2^-$ (based on the numbering depicted in the figure below)
\begin{align}
\nabla u^+ - \nabla u^- &= (\nabla \phi_0^+-\nabla \phi_3^-)\ u_0^+ + (\nabla \phi_1^+ - \nabla \phi_2^-)\ u^+_1 \\
&+ \nabla \phi_2^+\ u_2^+ - \nabla \phi_1^- u_1^- + \nabla \phi_3^+\ u_3^+ - \nabla \phi_0^-\ u_0^-  
\end{align}

So I observe that for the shared vertices the terms can be grouped and the calculations can be made on the $+$ element but for the non-shared vertices there are terms for both elements ($+,-$).

That being said, what is the meaning of $[\nabla \phi_i]$ if $(\star)$ cannot be written in the form
$$
\sum_j \int_F [\nabla \phi_i] [\nabla \phi_j]\ u_j \quad ?
$$

*Note.*

I can see that in `deal.ii` there is a class named [`FEInterfaceValues`](https://www.dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/classFEInterfaceValues.html#a956e2b00286ed98b6ad9e2a26d1f04bb) and probably what I am asking is what its function `dofmap` is actually doing, but I don't understand the implementation.

[image: Schematic of the FEM stencil]

Comment: I think I'm reasonably well positioned to answer the question :-) But I don't follow how you arrive at $\nabla u^+ - \nabla u^- = (\nabla \phi_0^+-\nabla \phi_3^-)\ u_0^+ + (\nabla \phi_1^+ - \nabla \phi_2^-)\ u^+_1
+ \nabla \phi_2^+\ u_2^+ - \nabla \phi_1^- u_1^- + \nabla \phi_3^+\ u_3^+ - \nabla \phi_0^-\ u_0^- $. Can you explain this formula?

Comment: Separately, are you assuming that your finite element is continuous or discontinuous?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you for your reply. I updated the post to explain the formula. I am assuming bilinear quadrilaterals, but added the DG flag since similar terms appear in DG-FEM.

Comment: So does $\phi_3^-$ live on the bottom cell, and at the same location as $\phi_0^+$?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Exactly. Sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go the grouping in the term $\nabla u^+-\nabla u^-$ mostly right but not quite. To see this, remember that the functions $\phi_i^{\pm}$ are discontinuous, and that consequently $u_0^+$ is not necessarily equal to $u_3^-$ -- if they were, you'd end up with a function that is continuous at that point. Instead, you need one degree of freedom *per adjacent cell* at each vertex.

The better way to write things is always to say that the shape functions form a basis. If you want to stick with the mesh with the two cells, then you will have eight shape functions $\phi_i^\pm$ (for $i=0\ldots 3$) and you need eight coefficients $u_i^\pm$. Your solution $u_h$ is then simply given by $u_h=\sum_{i=0}^3 \phi_i^- u_i^- + \sum_{i=0}^3 \phi_i^+ u_i^+$.

From this you can then see what the jump in the gradient is going to be:
$$
  [\nabla u] = \left[\nabla\left(\sum_{i=0}^3 \phi_i^- u_i^- + \sum_{i=0}^3 \phi_i^+ u_i^+\right)\right]
\\
  = \sum_{i=0}^3 [ \nabla \phi_i^-] u_i^- + \sum_{i=0}^3 [\nabla\phi_i^+] u_i^+.
$$
So your expansion in the last formula of the question is pretty much exactly right if you re-interpret the $u_j$ as my $u_i^\pm$.

What `FEInterfaceValues` does is pretty much the following: For a face, it gathers the indices of all of the shape functions that live on the neighboring cells. In your case, that's 8 shape functions, and so when assembling these jump terms along the face, you'll have to compute an $8\times 8$ matrix of jump contributions to the global matrix. But if you had, for example, continuous elements, there would only be 6 (unique) degrees of freedom adjacent, and so the `dofmap` variable would only contain 6 entries (of the global indices of the corresponding degrees of freedom).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. In my question I assumed continuous shape functions, hence the grouping. Could you please define the terms $[\nabla \phi_i^+]$ and $[\nabla \phi_i^-]$? To me it looks like $[\nabla \phi_i^+] \equiv \nu \cdot \nabla \phi_i^+$, since $\nabla \phi_i^+ \equiv 0$ if you approach from the `$-$' FE.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification regarding the deal.ii functions. Currently I am writing my own code but I may have to migrate to deal.ii for bigger problems, so it's good to know it's already implemented.

Comment: Yes, your expansion of what the jump of a shape function is is correct in the case of a discontinuous shape function.

Comment: Shouldn't $[\nabla \phi_i^+] = \nu \cdot \nabla \phi_i^+$ and $[\nabla \phi_i^-] = \nu \cdot \nabla \phi_i^-$ hold for any shape function since $\phi^+, \ \phi^-$ have support only on $+$ and $-$ FE, respectively? Why would it have to be a discontinuous one?

Comment: No, for continuous functions, $\phi_0^+$ and $\phi_3^-$ would denote the same shape function. Similarly, $u_0^+=u_3^-$ are the same unknowns.